# Equivalence between small distance and high energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, particle-physics, fourier-transform, distance

I see in a lot of particle physics literature statements along the lines of: 'This is valid for high energies (small distances)'. Exactly what do we mean by small distances in this case? From QFT, QM and other physics courses, the connection between small distance and high energy makes intuitive sense, but I am wondering if there is a concrete connection that authors have in mind?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156925/how-come-smaller-weaker-particles-are-more-massive-have-higher-energies).

Answer (score 7):

In HEP, where (in units of *c*=1) momenta are much larger than masses, so they are tantamount to energies, the fundamental scale relation of QM, $[x,p]=i\hbar$, comes to bear. The de Broglie relation ${\lambda\over 2\pi}= \hbar/p$ of the particles/waves involved relates distances to momenta/energies *inversely*.

Consequently, "small distance" is a synonym for "high energy" or momentum. So, analogously to diffractive crystallography, one probes ever smaller distance scales with ever higher enery/momentum scattering probes.

In HEP natural units, (ℏ=1) this is codified by the duality of the units for distance or energy,
such as the  radius of a proton being 4 GeV$^{-1}$ actually [meaning](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/5elementary.pdf)
$$
4 \mathrm {GeV}^{-1} (\hbar c) = 8\cdot 10^{-16}{\mathrm m}~.
$$

Comment: Yes I see the connection between SMALL distance and HIGH energy. My question was a bit unclear I think, what I was wondering about is what the actual distance is in this case. Is it distance between interacting particles or something else?

Comment: It is a general statement applied the way the uncertainty principle is applied. It could be the size of a hadron, or the interaction distance in a scattering experiment (diffraction), or, multiplied by *c*, a characteristic *time*, such as the lifetime of a particle, or the time of an interaction such as hadronization, etc...

Answer (score 4):

Connections between energy and distance tend to involve the factor

$$
\hbar c= \rm 197\ eV\ nm=197\ MeV\ fm
$$

and some additional factors from doing algebra. The algebraic factors tend to be values like $\frac13$ or $\sqrt 6$, but it is unusual to do a page of first-principles algebra and come up a purely numerical factor of a thousand.

The most common example is a Yukawa-type force mediated by a massive particle, which has potential energy

$$
V=\alpha\hbar c\frac{e^{-r/r_0}}{r},
\qquad\text{where }r_0=\frac{\hbar c}{m c^2}
$$

Electromagnetism, where the photon is massless, is a Yukawa interaction in the limit $r_0\to\infty$, with $\alpha_\text{e.m.}≈10^{-2}$ the fine structure constant. In a meson-mediated model of nucleon-nucleon interactions, the longest-range component comes from the pion, whose mass $mc^2=140\rm\ MeV$ corresponds to a distance $r_0=1.4\ \rm fm$. For nucleons many femtometers apart, the pion-mediated attraction is exponentially suppressed. At shorter distances, you have to include heavier mesons in your calculations. At *very* high energies, you even have “forces” which mediated by the giga-eV weak bosons.

Comment: I have also wondered about OP's question in the past. In his example, saying that "Equation X is valid for large energies or small distances"... if energy here is the COM energy of some colliding particles, and distance is the distance between them... in terms of as-precise-as-possible logical argument, how can you argue that the existence of a conversion factor (as in your answer) implies that the "high energy" and "close together particles" should be related? Is it actually just based on the intuition that repulsive particles get closer when collided with higher energy?

Comment: Basically I am curious if this can be made any less rule-of-thumb-y, and more directly logical/deductive. I have always automatically had some skepticism of hand-wavy arguments, though I also find them useful.

Comment: Without a specific quote to structure a response, it's hard to be anything but hand-wavy. But consider the well-known derivation that $\gamma-1\to\frac{v^2}{2c^2}$ in the small-speed limit, recovering the Newtonian kinetic energy. That sort of first-order approximation is frequently a way to quantify "in the limit" statements, where at high energies the "small" parameter might be $mc^2/E$.

Comment: I think my question was a bit unclear, I was mainly asking about what *distance* means in this case. From your answer, it seems distance in this case probably refers to distance between interacting particles?

Comment: @Tjommen Yes, the $r$ in the Yukawa energy $\alpha\hbar c/r$ is the distance between the interacting particles.